# Pass problematic string from client to server and get the exact same string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I haven't been able to pass the following game record from my client to my server:

```
[Event "fics server game, rated blitz match"]
[Site "Internet Chess Server: freechess.org 5000"]
[Date "1999.11.07"]
[Time "06:26:??"]
[Round "-"]
[White "spock"]
[Black "kirk"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[WhiteElo "1074"]
[BlackElo "1134"]
[TimeControl "300+12"]
[ECO "C20 KP, Patzer opening"]
[Source "Marcel van Kervinck"]

1. e4 e5 2. Qh5 Nf6 3. Qxe5+ Qe7 4. Qxe7+ Bxe7 5. f3 d5 6. d3 Nc6 7. c3 d4 8.
Bd2 Be6 9. b4 dxc3 10. Bxc3 O-O 11. g4 Nxb4 12. Bxb4 Bxb4+ 13. Ke2 Rfe8 14. g5
Nh5 15. Ke3 Bd5 16. a3 Ba5 17. Nd2 f5 18. Kd4 Bc6 19. Nc4 Rad8+ 20. Ke3 f4+ 21.
Ke2 Bc3 22. Rc1 Bd4 23. Na5 Be3 24. Rb1 Rd7 25. Nxb7 Bxb7 26. Rxb7 Red8 27. Rb3
g6 28. Bh3 Rd4 29. Be6+ Kf8 30. Nh3 Ng7 31. Bd5 Ne8 32. Rhb1 Nd6 33. Rb4 Rxb4
34. Rxb4 Bc5 35. Rb1 Bxa3 36. Nxf4 Ke7 37. e5 Nc8 38. e6 Nb6 39. Ra1 Bd6 40.
Ke3 Ra8
{Game drawn by mutual agreement} 1/2-1/2

{ FEN r7/p1p1k2p/1n1bP1p1/3B2P1/5N2/3PKP2/7P/R7 w - - }
```

my html

```
$("#ParseButton").on("click", function(){
        $("#output").append("Parsing Started" + "\n");
        readFile($("#selectfile").get(0)); 
    });  

  function readFile(input) {
        let file = input.files[0];
        reader.readAsText(file);
    };
  let gamesstring = reader.result
  let gamestringsarray = gamesstring.split("\[Event");
  let gamestring = "[Event" + gamestringsarray[2];  
  console.log(gamestring); //logs the string I showed correctly

  $.ajax("/postmoves", {
        //dataType: "",
        type: "post",
        data: gamestring,
        contentType: "text/plain",
        //contentType: "false",
        success: function(){}
  });
```

Server Side

```
var express = require('express');
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/', async function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
module.exports = router;
```

I've tried a lot of combinations of contentType, body-parser, JSON.parse, JSON.stringify but cannot get the string on the server.  Now I can't even see the string inside req.body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I missed a combination.  including body-parser.text() and choosing contentType = "text/plain" enabled me to pass the string. I guess I expected a string to pass without need for middleware and forgot to try this obvious combination.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have bodyParser, one way to handle things would be :

1. Set your gamesstring to return an object instead of string.
2. In html, set contentType to be 'application/json'
3. In your server, uncomment your bodyParser line
4. In your server, add the following line before your router.post...
   app.use(bodyParser.json ()) ;